# Overloading template operator in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++17, sfinae

Given a base class and a derived class, which both provide conditionally enabled operators for specific parameter types using SFINAE:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Base
{
public:
    template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_scalar_v<T>>* = nullptr>
    void operator>>(T& value) {
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    using Base::operator>>;

    template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_scalar_v<T>>* = nullptr>
    void operator>>(T& value) {
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int foo;

    Base base;
    base >> foo; // this works

    Derived derived;
    derived >> foo; // this doesn't work, the operator from the base class is not considered
}
```

then calling an operator defined in the base class on an instance of the derived class will not work, even though it should have been made visible by the appropriate `using Base::operator>>;` declaration. Why? How can the operator from the base class be made usable without verbosely repeating the declaration/definition?

The problem does not occur if the operator in question is not a template in the base class.

Edit: Tested with msvc 15.9.7 as well as clang.

Comment: Make the operators free functions. Have you tried that?

Comment: I reproduce the problem with clang++ but not with g++. I add another question: who's right?

Comment: Same problem with a simple template method (not necessarily an operator); I suppose it's a clang++ and msvc bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that a using declaration only brings the declarations of functions and function templates into a derived class that have signatures which are not overridden by members of the derived class [[namespace.udecl]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#15). So this code should indeed not compile.

Use free functions instead of class members to fix the problem:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Base
{
public:
    template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_scalar_v<T>>* = nullptr>
    friend void operator>>(Base&, T& value) {
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_scalar_v<T>>* = nullptr>
    friend void operator>>(Derived&, T& value) {
    }
};

int main()
{
    int foo;

    Base base;
    base >> foo;

    Derived derived;
    derived >> foo;
}
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Aclass+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++template%3Cclass+T,+std::enable_if_t%3Cstd::is_scalar_v%3CT%3E%3E*+%3D+nullptr%3E%0A++++friend+void+operator%3E%3E(Base%26,+T%26+value)+%7B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+Derived:+public+Base%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++template%3Cclass+T,+std::enable_if_t%3C!!std::is_scalar_v%3CT%3E%3E*+%3D+nullptr%3E%0A++++friend+void+operator%3E%3E(Derived%26,+T%26+value)+%7B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++int+foo%3B%0A%0A++++Base+base%3B%0A++++base+%3E%3E+foo%3B%0A%0A++++Derived+derived%3B%0A++++derived+%3E%3E+foo%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:59.11169170476812,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:40.88830829523188,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)